# Two python codes to find second lowest marks

Tags: python

I have been told to solve this HackerRank problem:

Print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade in Physics; if there are multiple students, order their names alphabetically and print each one on a new line.

Link to Question:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem

Now, additional constraint apart from that mentioned on HackerRank Page:

1. No use of lambda function
2. Minimal or no use of List functions (apart from sorting)
3. Try to not create additional (duplicate) list (a new list which doesn't have the minimum value of original list. Thus, minimum of this list is second minimum of original list.)

Here's my first code.
Tried to make it as basic as possible(without use of many in-built function)

```
data= []
names = []

for _ in range(int(raw_input())):
    name = raw_input()
    score = float(raw_input())

    data.append([name,score])


# chossing minimum and second minimum form the first two scores.
if data[0][1] > data[1][1]:
    smin = data[0][1]
    mins = data[1][1]
else:
    mins = data[0][1]
    smin = data[1][1]

for i in range(len(data)):

    if data[i][1] < mins:
        smin = mins
        mins = data[i][1]

    elif data[i][1] > mins and data[i][1] < smin:
        smin = data[i][1]

for i in data:
    if i[1] == smin:
        names.append(i[0])

names.sort()
for i in names:
    print(i)
```

This code runs good for all test cases except test case 3(hidden).

Now, I wrote another code.
This code breaks rule 3 of additional constraints(mentioned above) but runs perfectly.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(raw_input())
    student = []
    l = []
    for i in range(x):
        name = raw_input()
        score = float(raw_input())
        y = [name,score]
        student.append(y)


    lowest = 0
    for i in range(len(student)):
        if(student[lowest][1] > student[i][1]):
            lowest = i

    l_marks = student[lowest][1]
    stud = []
    for i in student:
        if(l_marks != i[1]):
            stud.append(i)

    lowest = 0
    for i in range(len(stud)):
        if(stud[lowest][1] > stud[i][1]):
            lowest = i

    l_marks = stud[lowest][1]
    l.append(stud[lowest][0])
    del(stud[lowest])
    for i in stud:
        if(l_marks == i[1]):
            l.append(i[0])

    l = sorted(l)
    for i in l:
        print(i)
```

This code is totally correct. Runs good for all test cases.

Now, I can't figure out why is the code 1 not covering all cases and how did code 2 run correctly??

**What, is wrong in code 1?**

Note:
I have seen many alternate codes(from GeeksforGeeks and StackOverFlow) which are correct. **I don't want link to any new code which will give me correct answer. Instead I would like to know, what is wrong with code 1?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fatal flaw in your first code extract is the bit where you set up `mins` and `smin`:

```py
# chossing minimum and second minimum form the first two scores.
if data[0][1] > data[1][1]:
    smin = data[0][1]
    mins = data[1][1]
else:
    mins = data[0][1]
    smin = data[1][1]
```

What happens here if the first two people have the same score? `mins` and `smin` will be the same.

Consider this input:

```
3
foo
10
bar
10
baz
50
```

When you get to considering `baz` in your for loop, you will have `mins == 10` *and* `smin == 10`.

So, when you try to work out if `baz`'s score should be the second minimum, there is a problem:

```py
elif data[i][1] > mins and data[i][1] < smin:
    smin = data[i][1]
```

Because `mins` and `smin` are the same, you won't set a new value for `smin`.

Your second programme solves this problem by taking a different approach. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

What if the first two scores are equal and negative?

```
For example: [['John': -15], ['Nic': -15], ['Mike': 20]]
```

In this scenario your code sets both `minimum` and `second_minimum` to `-15` at:

```
if data[0][1] > data[1][1]:
    smin = data[0][1]
    mins = data[1][1]
else:
    mins = data[0][1]
    smin = data[1][1]
```

Then at this part of the  code, your `smin` is `-15` :

```
for i in data:
    if i[1] == smin:
        names.append(i[0])
```

But the `second_minimum` is actually `20`

You just appended the `names` list with `['John', 'Nic']`